# css: mystery "margin"

Tags: css, layout, padding, margin, reset

Whenever I have two elements side by side horizontally with right and/or left padding and/or margin specified, there is often space between the elements over and above what I've specified. I'm hoping someone can tell me how to eliminate that space (without something crufty like a negative margin).

Please note: I am not looking for alternative multi-column CSS layout techniques. I know there are loads of them out there and this issue is bigger than just a column layout issue.

Below is the markup and styles for a [working example page](http://www.jamestbaker.com/test4.php).  [Here's a partial screenshot of that page](http://www.jamestbaker.com/test4.png) that shows left elements selected with Firebug. The mysterious space in question is to the right and is marked with a red asterisk. There are no reset styles included but I've plugged in Eric Meyers' reset and it didn't solve the problem.

```
    <div id="side-a"> 
           <p>
        Lorem ipsum ....
        </p> 
    </div> 
    <div id="side-b"> 
           <p>
        Nunc dapibus....
        </p> 
    </div>

    <div id="website-footer"> 
           <ul id="legal-information"> 
                  <li>Copyright 2011</li> 
                  <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li> 
           </ul> 
    </div>

    div#side-a,
    div#side-b {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 17px 17px 0;
    }

    div#side-a {
           vertical-align: top;
    }

    div#side-b {
           background: #999;
    }

    ul {
           padding-bottom: 17px;
           list-style: none outside none;
    }

    ul li {
           line-height: 17px;
           margin-left: 17px;
    }

    div#website-footer ul#legal-information {
           float: left;
    }

    div#website-footer ul#legal-information li {
           border-left: 1px solid #29443C;
           display: inline;
           margin: 17px 0;
           padding-left: 8px;
    }

    div#website-footer ul#legal-information li:first-child {
           border-left: medium none;
           padding: 0 8px 0 0;
    }
```

Comment: did you try a reset css? your browser could be doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's natural because of `inline-block`. Simple solution is to kill whitespace.

http://work.arounds.org/issue/6/unwanted-white-space-between-inline-block-elements/

There are other css based workarounds such as setting a font size of 0 on the body, but AFAIK they aren't as consistent/reliable. I could be wrong though.

Comment: The link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this Css:

```
div#side-a,
div#side-b {
  float: left
  width: 200px;
  padding: 17px 17px 0;
}
```

And added in Css for the footer:

```
#website-footer {
    clear: both;
}
```

And this fixed the issue.

I usually float the elements when I want them next to each other.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'd prefer to not use float, if possible. While I've done this myself many times in the past it takes the elements out of the normal flow of the page which makes parent elements collapse vertically. So, it works, but it's not an ideal solution that can be used in all cases. I should have phrased the need as 'where does this whitespace come from' -- sorry!

Comment: Thats ok. Ive always been a user of floats over display